# Bootstrap hover function and border display

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to create a small panel with an image and trying to figure out two things for it. I can't seem to get the border around the image to fit it. There is a small gap and I want the border to fit around the image. Also I want it so that when the user hovers over the image the border around the image turns yellow. For some reason those I can't seem to get these two things to work. Any help on this matter would be great

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

   <div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <a href="/recipes/arthritis-soother-36">

                       <img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive media-object" src=http://www.bodybysimone.com/wp-content/uploads/green-juice-mbd108052_vert.jpg >

                </a>
            </div>

    </div>
     <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>

.panel-default{
  width: 500px;
}

.panel-body hover{
   background-color: yellow;
   border size: 20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zct176v/3/)

Comment: sounds like there's some padding between the border and the image.  Also, in your CSS for hover to work properly write it as: .panel-body:hover{

Comment: ^^ you were missing the colon :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your css

```
.panel-default{
  width: 500px;
}
.panel-body .img-thumbnail{padding:0px;border:1px solid transparent} /*remove padding and add transparent border*/
.panel-body:hover  .img-thumbnail{
   border-color: yellow; /*change the transparent border to yellow*/
   border size: 20px;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1zct176v/5/)**

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted which will be helpful for others with same question.

Comment: Ah ye sorry i did, just had to wait the extra minutes :)